# How to preserve the tree state in an implementation of the common navigator in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I have implemented the common navigator in a custom perspective. When I modify a file and save it, the entire tree collapses. I tried fixing it by using the refresh(object) method instead of refresh() in the resource change listener. But then a newly created project(a custom definition) does not show up in the navigator unless the application is restarted. That is because the project is a virtual node and the entire workspace needs to be refreshed using refresh(). I tried using  conditional statements but that too doesn't work because when a file is saved, the change goes up stage by stage to the root of the tree which again needs refresh() and that in turn collapses my tree. Is there any workaround ?

Comment: Did you find an answer to this question somewhere else in the meantime? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I do it for my navigator based view:

```
/**
     * Try to preserve the collapsed tree state of its nodes after an update of
     * the view or the model
     * 
     * @param theRoot
     *            the parent element
     */
    private static void preserveTreeState(Object theRoot) {
        int i = 0, j = 0;
        Object elem[] = treeViewer.getExpandedElements();
        treeViewer.setInput(theRoot);
        treeViewer.expandAll();
        Object elem1[] = treeViewer.getExpandedElements();
        treeViewer.collapseAll();
        while (i < elem.length) {
            j = 0;
            while (j < elem1.length) {
                if (elem[i] instanceof ObjectParent
                && elem1[j] instanceof ObjectParent) {
                    if (!((ObjectParent) elem[i]).getFText().equals("//")
                            && !((ObjectParent) elem1[j]).getFText()
                                    .equals("//")) {
                        if (((ObjectParent) elem[i]).getFText().equals(
                                ((ObjectParent) elem1[j]).getFText())) {
                            treeViewer.expandToLevel(elem1[j], 1);
                        }
                    }
                }
...
//here I compare all the possible custom objects in my custom navigator
...
```